# Should I use loop in the single.php file?

Tags: loop

I read many tutorials, and checked many premium/free theme's source and most of them use loop in the single.php file.

The single.php file only displays one post, so I think `the_post()` is enough, while is unnecessary. Is there any reason why these themes (twentyfifteen, twentytwelve, etc..) use loop in the single.php file?

Answer (score 4):

Stricktly speaking, you don't need the loop in single post pages, you only need the call to `the_post()`.

The reason for `the_post()` is that `the_post()` sets the `$post` global value to the single post post object

Answer (score 3):

If you want to maintain 100% compatibility with all plugins, you need to use the loop on single.php. The reason is that there are `loop_start` and `loop_end` actions which get triggered on the first and last call to `have_posts()`.

Comment: So, basically if i drop the loop, there is a chance that i miss some events triggered by it? Does WordPress itself have such events or they are only added by plugins?

Comment: Correct. There's nothing currently in core that gets triggered on these.

Answer (score 1):

More precisions as i can't comment the given answers. The Wordpress documentation isn't precise from a developer point of view, and i was much confused myself until i opened the WP code.

**global post**

Unlike what is claimed in a given response (Pieter), the global `$post` is already set when landing on a single template (either standard or custom post). It should hold the first and unique post. I tried it myself displaying the post before and after a sequential loop, then going beyond to see what happens.

```
// in single.php or single-{cpt}.php
get_the_header();
global $post;

echo "<h3>before loop</h3>";
var_dump($post);  // already contains the queried post!

echo "<h3>in loop [i=0]</h3>";
the_post();
var_dump($post); // still the same!

echo "<h3>in loop [i=1]</h3>";
the_post();
var_dump($post); // not set (NULL)
```

**the WP loop**

So, for accessing the standard fields of the posts you don't strictly need to call `the_post()`. However, as Milo mentioned, this might create some conflicts with plugins or lead to weird behaviours because your content will be displayed out of the loop. Not only it will miss the `loop_start` and `loop_end` actions, but the WP query holds an internal state called `in_the_loop` that would not be set. For instance, a callback in the content calling `in_the_loop()` would get `false` while you could expect to get `true` when reading some content. And this is quite misleading as you are not in a real loop... a loop should only be for archives involving multiple posts but this is just a bad semantics choice in WP.

You can see this here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/the_post/

```
public function the_post() {
global $post;
$this->in_the_loop = true;

if ( $this->current_post == -1 ) // loop has just started
    /**
     * Fires once the loop is started.
     *
     * @since 2.0.0
     *
     * @param WP_Query &$this The WP_Query instance (passed by reference).
     */
    do_action_ref_array( 'loop_start', array( &$this ) );

$post = $this->next_post();
$this->setup_postdata( $post );
```

}

**a while loop?**

The last question would be the need for a `while (has_posts())` loop which doesn't make much sense as you are in a single post template and a unique post should have been found. Some claim it is for consistency to fit in a general case as for other templates, but from a pure developer point of view  it's a bit confusing. Actually you should rather check `if (has_posts())` in case of a bad call, so the main reason is more for robustness if ever a redirection goes wrong. Given that, you can use `while (has_posts())` to match a general template but this is more of a subjective matter.

**TL;DR**

To loop or not to loop? A `while` loop is not necessary but `the_post()` should be called at least once, not for loading the post but for consistency with the internal states (WP_Query). A check with `has_posts()` should be called once before, for robustness.