# Can't get or display post thumbnail in wordpress

Tags: plugins, post-thumbnails

i'm working on a WordPress plugin and i'm trying to display/get the post thumbnail below the post on my "Related posts" part. I tried many things which are supposed to work but not for me ... here is the code (**on my plugin.php file**):

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page' ) );

if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo ('there is a thumbnail');
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), "thumbnail"); // nothing
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); // nothing
    echo var_dump(get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), "thumbnail")); //string '' (length=0)
    echo var_dump(get_the_post_thumbnail()); //string '' (length=0)
    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); // nothing
    the_post_thumbnail(); // nothing
}
else {
    echo ('there is no thumbnail');
}
```

first i thought that there were no thumbnail for my post but **my first echo returned "there is a thumbnail"** and all the rest doesn't return anything ... so i don't understand... what is missing ?

Thanks

**Edit:**

here is the current full code in my **plugin.php** file:

```
function Similar_Article ($content) {
    if (is_single() || is_page()) {
        the_post();
        $similar_to_add = '';
        $id = get_the_ID();
        $content_and_similar = $content . '<br><br>'; //spaces between post and related posts

        /* many methods called to find my related posts */

        if (has_post_thumbnail()){
            $content_and_similar .= get_the_post_thumbnail(); // it works
        }
        else {
            $imageData = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id ( $id ), 'thumbnail'); 
            $content_and_similar .= '<img src=" '.$imageData[0].' ">';
        }

        $content_and_similar .= $similar_to_add;
        return $content_and_similar;
    }
    else {
        return $content;
    }
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'Similar_Article' );
```

my function works if there is a thumbnail but display nothing if there is no thumbnail...

Answer (score 0):

Please notice, `has_post_thumbnail()` does not only check to see if the post has a featured image, but also checks if there is an image in the post itself. There is a quote from [WordPress Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/):

> It’s worth noting that `has_post_thumbnail()` does not just check for
>   the Featured Image as the Codex User Contributed Note suggests. If a
>   post contains no defined featured image but it does contain an image
>   in the content this function will still return TRUE.

I suggest you use `if (get_the_post_thumbnail() != '')` instead of `if (has_post_thumbnail())`.

Comment: thx for your answer, but I don't really understand this "Loop", I want to display my related posts thumbnail below **a specific post, the one that is opened** .. so why this loop on all posts ?

Comment: The reason is explained [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198704/should-i-use-loop-in-the-single-php-file). You don't really need the loop since i already check if we are on a single page (`is_singluar()`), but the important thing is that you have to setup the post data before you can access it.

Comment: hum ok for the loop, but I want to display something even if there is no thumbnail set ... so i tried that 

`if (has_post_thumbnail()){
 echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
}
else {
 $imageData = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id ( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail'); ?>
     
 <img style="float:left; padding-right: 35px;" src="<?php echo $imageData[0]; ?>"/>
     
<?php   }`

but it's not working ...

Comment: @CédricCosson Are you directly using the code in your plugin.php file? or wrapped in a function and then calling the function in your single.php?

Comment: yes i use the code directly inside my plugin.php file, I can't write directly in my single.php file because i'm creating a plugin and i need that all i do stay in my plugin directory ... but maybe there is a hook that i can use ? Currently I have a function that get the post content and add my related post below and then, I hook it using `add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_function' );` is that wrong ?

Comment: @CédricCosson I assume you are using the code posted [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content#Featured_Image)? It's always nice to add the full code you are using. It's really hard to guess what's happening behind the curtain, if you just post a piece of it.

Comment: i edited my post, there is the full code

Comment: @CédricCosson Please check the updated answer.

Comment: i did exactly what u suggested, and the condition `if (get_the_post_thumbnail() != '')` is not working in any cases (I tried with  and without thumbnail) and I'm always in the `else`

Comment: Never mind, it's working, but when I try to get the first image from the content when there is no thumbnail, nothing appear... code : `else {
   $imageData = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id ( $id ), 'thumbnail'); 
   $similar_to_add .= 'no thumb ' . '<img src="'.$imageData[0].'">';
  }`

Comment: @CédricCosson Your else block will not run at all, as long as there is an image in your post. So, `wp_get_attachment_image_src` won't run and you won't be getting any images from the post.

Comment: You suggested me to use this condition `if (get_the_post_thumbnail() != '')` which is supposed to valid the `if` block only if there is a thumbnail as you said. so i don't understand why the else block will not run... actually i have no thumbnail and it run but i think that i use badly the function inside